# Mostrar formularios en twig con symfony

Tags: symfony3, twig

Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de comentarios en symfony pero al momento de renderizar el formulario dentro de un for de la siguiente manera

código de twig:

```
{% for publicacion in publicaciones %}
    {{form(form}}
{% endfor %}
```

el formulario se muestra una sola vez y no se muestra por cada publicación que se halla hecho

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de crear solo un formolario en tu controllador, crea un array con un formulario para cada publicación:

```
$formArray=[]
foreach($publicaciones as $publicacion)
{ 
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($publicacion);
    $formArray[$publicacion]=$form;
}
```

De esta forma tienes un array que utiliza la publicación como índice y el form como valor. luego en la vista:

```
{% for publicacion in publicaciones %}
    {{form(formArray[publicaion]}}
{% endfor %}
```